# How to get date and time with Javascript in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to get the current date and time in Selenium IDE (latest version 3.7.4) in a format like this `2019-05-21 12:35:23` that is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

I'm new to javascript and what I found so far is that in Javascript the current date is obtained from system using `new Date();`

So I've set the following commands in Selenium IDE

```
1)
Command: execute script
Target: new Date();
Value: currentdate

2)
Command: echo
Target: $(currentdate)
Value:
```

But it seems `Date();` is not working and is not stored in variable `currentdate`. This is the output

```
executeScript on new Date(); with value currentdate OK
echo: undefined
'Untitled' completed successfully
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question while looking for a way to do this myself. I found the answer elsewhere, so I thought I'd share it here in hopes of helping others.

You need to begin your JavaScript line with "`return`", like this:

```
return new Date();
```

This should place a verbose `Date()` value in your `currentDate` variable, which you can echo or use elsewhere.  You'll probably want to format it using the `toLocaleString()` method, though, like this:

```
return new Date().toLocaleString();
```

That should return the date/time more closely formatted to your needs.